# Phonegap/Cordova InAppBrowser not launching

Tags: javascript, cordova, browser, in-app

I am not sure why but when I do the following

```
<img id="buttons" src="https://qikout.com/apppics/MerchantPromo.png" style="margin:1% auto; width:99% !important;" onclick="openextlink('https://qikout.com');"/>

function openextlink(url)
{
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');
//window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url, { showLocationBar: true });
}
```

it works fine. But when I want to run the openextlink from within another function it does not open the window, instead it loads the page but just does not show it to the user.

for e.g.

```
function scan(){

    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result) {
            if(result.format != "QR_CODE")
            {
            alert("That is not a valid google Tag");
            }
            else
            {
                n = result.text.split(".com/");
                loadpet();

                    //alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                    //     "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                    //     "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                    //     "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);

            }
        }, function(error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );

}

function loadpet(){
    $("#buttons").trigger("click");
    var link = "http://www.google.com/" + n[1];
    openextlink(link);
}
```

it works via

```
<div onclick="scan();" class="menu-right"></div>
```

Basically it scans fine, it gets the result it moves the result to the loadpet function and even sends it to the openextlink function however does not popup the viewer.

Comment: what is the value inside n[1]?

Answer (score 0):

Your window.open code looks right (based on how InAppBrowser works as of Cordova 3.0).

Can you confirm all of the following?

- The InAppBrowser plugin has an entry in your /#myapp#/platforms/#platform#/www/cordova_plugins.js file?
- The InAppBrowser plugin folder is in /#myapp#/platforms/#platform#/plugins/
- The related SRC files for InAppBrowser are in the platform folder as well (for example IOS plugin src files are: /#myapp#/platforms/#platform#/#appname#/Plugins/)

Also if all the above are confirmed but still no luck you might try appending a console.log('inappbrowser.js file has loaded!') line to the end of your inappbrowser.js file to confirm it is indeed loading (assuming you have setup the debug console and can view the output).